# I'm trying to use Textarea in my project. However, sometimes the resize button (at right bottom corner) is disappeared?

Tags: html, textarea

[enter image description here][1]

there is no resize buttom. Sometimes it is there. When I browse other pages and come back again, it disappears. I'm using Chrome. Anyone help, Thank you so much.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRDSn.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied any css on the textarea? If yes, please show me.

or try adding this css code:

```
textarea{ 
 resize: both;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

If this doens't work, you should try important too:

```
textarea{ 
 resize: both !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem. I'm using a html component which wraps the textarea and the resize attribute is set to none by default. I just override it as vertical !important then it works. Thank you so much to give me the hint.

Comment: oh great, you should mark question as answered then.
Have a great day.